# clientHeight of Element in PDF different to Element in Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'am trying to identify with javascript if I need to force a page break in my document.

One element that is overflow hidden. I loop through each of the elements within this document. I remove all last childs until the height of the element within the overflow:hidden element is smaller. Now I know, when to page break and I push all removed childs in the new page.

Works fine in browser. But not in PDF...

I'am using http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

See problem here: [Left: PDF, Right: Browser (Chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T8VZ.jpg)

Height of 3262px vs 358px...

Same if I use .clientHeight or jQuery .height().

Does anyone know a workaround to get heights the same?

Some code:

```
    function isOverflowed(element){
        // return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;
        // console.log(element.clientHeight);
        // console.log(element.parent().height() +'>'+ element.height());
        return element.parent().height() < element.height();
    }
    // var daysWrapper = document.getElementById('days');
    // var days = daysWrapper.querySelectorAll(".section.day");
    var days = $('#days .section.day');
    // console.log(days);

    days.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var area = $this.find('.day-info');
      var content = area.children();
      var lasts = $( '<div class="lasts">' );
      var test = 0;
      while(isOverflowed(content)) {
        var last  = content.children().last();
        // lasts.append( $( last ) );
        last.clone().prependTo(lasts);
        last.remove();
        test++;
        if (test > 6) break;
      }
      content.find('h1').html(area.height() + ' - ' + content.height());
      if (lasts.children().length ) {
        var newPage = $this.clone();
        newPage.insertAfter($this);
        newPage.find('.day-image').remove();
        newPage.find('.day-info').removeClass('overflow');
        newPage.find('.day-info').children().html(lasts.html());
      }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about this but the conversion process of HTML to PDF probably ignores javascript code

Comment: It does not ignore javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `@media print` media query?

Comment: For what should I use @media print?

Comment: You can target the print/PDF styling with that CSS query instead of resorting to javascript, might solve your issue

Comment: I'am styling my PDF with CSS. But I can't handle the page break depending on the text within an element and style the page after page break with a different style.

My content is generated dynamically.

Comment: Check this out: http://prntscr.com/a0gw0m Each element in PDF has a different height value than it has in browser... Confusing...